# ASP.NET Error System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET web project that has been running for years. Last year we changed one of the data sources to MYSQL so added MySqlConnector from NuGet. Just recently the application started throwing the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference." This error only occurs when we try to connect to MySql using MySqlConnetor. All NuGet packages have been updated and using .NET framework 4.6.1. The assembly binding portion of the webconfig is;

```
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Similar questions have been ask in this forum and I have tried all suggested solutions, but am still getting the error. This must have been caused by an OS update as the error started occurring on the live server as well as my development machine.

Comment: If this is a web application (not web site), then try clean solution, and then delete everything in the bin folder. Then do a re-build all.

Comment: It is a website. Building solution does not expose any errors.

Comment: It seems the binding information is stored somewhere other than web.config. I edit the binding redirect to different values and the error continues to call for the old version of the dll. Not sure where it is pulling this info.

Comment: I tried deleting the bin folder and uninstalling all the NuGet packages involved with MySqlconnector. Then reinstalled. The latest error is "System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. "
It seems I am going in circles. I don't know how to resolve this issue, nor do I undersand why this started in the first place. I really do need some guidance.

Comment: Are you building with any cpu, or forcing to x64 (if not, do try this).

Comment: I ended up abandoning the GitHub MySqlConnector. Downloaded the MySqlData.dll from Oracle and updated code to use that. All the dependencies not required. The site is set to Any cpu now. Have not tried changing to x64. Using the dll directly seems to have solved my issue, and it works on the hosting server. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Ok, was not a lot of help, but looks like it is working. good luck!